# After deploying to heroky scripts and css not available

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am new in heroku. Locally project works fine but after deploying vendor scripts files are not available. Their paths are redirected to main page.

Here is the deployed version with errors https://salty-woodland-8424.herokuapp.com/.

[image]

In nodeJs file i use

```
var express = require('express');    
var path = require('path');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();

function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str).set('filename', path);
}

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'server/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(stylus.middleware(
    {
        src: __dirname + '/public',
        compile: compile
    }
));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

console.log(mongoose.version);
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://****:****@ds033390.mongolab.com:33390/mymongodb');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error...'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log('mymongodb db opened');
});

var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({message: String});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var mongoMessage;
Message.findOne().exec(function(err, messageDoc) {
    mongoMessage = messageDoc.message;
});

app.get('/partials/:partialPath', function(req, res) {
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        mongoMessage: mongoMessage
    });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '...');
```

What it can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. I think, I asked incorrect question. The problem was in missing bower command installation for dependencies when deploy.